# What is causing my toilet to flush by itself periodically?

Tags: toilet

I have an American Standard toilet, with interior pieces that look pretty new.  The toilet suffers from a ghost flush, roughly every fifteen minutes the water kicks on for a few seconds to fill the tank.

The flapper (part that lifts when the toilet is flushed) does not have a gasket to replace, and seems new (is clean).  It does have a dial I can turn on it, though I'm not sure what that is supposed to do.

Is there anything else I should check that could be causing my toilet to run intermittently?

[image: interior of toilet]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May look new but the flapper is probably leaking. Put a few drops of food dye in the tank then keep an eye on the bowl and see if the color migrates to the bowl. If it does then the flapper is leaking.

Comment: OP...I bet this is the right answer. I had this problem recently and replacing the flapper fixed it. However, if I had it to do over knowing what I know now, I wish I'd removed the old flapper and thoroughly cleaned the underside of it (by hand, *not* in a dishwasher), then replaced it to see if it made a better seal. After the fact I noticed my old flapper had a light coating of scummy build-up developed over time, and I suspect this was the reason for the poor seal and the slow leaks. Cleaning it first might have saved me $30 or so..